# why do I get so many errors in release mode WP7

Tags: windows-phone-7, release

I have a question about the release mode of the Windows Phone application build. When I deploy it in debug mode, it works fine, but when I run it in release mode, I get like a gazillion error messages from the .g.i.cs files, stating that áll the members have ambiguity with some other member. How do I resolve this, and why does it do this? Also, I already published an app onto the beta marketplace, whereof the .XAP file was created in debug mode, and it did not give any trouble with the user. So, is Release mode even mandatory?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried a Clean + Build? Release mode is not mandatory for app certification, although it is preferable (no debug info = better performance & smaller size)

Comment: @PedroLamas Clean + Build is the same as Rebuild? I tried rebuild, but stil;l get the same errors.

Comment: Close Visual Studio, delete the "bin" and "obj" subfolders from the project and then try Rebuild again!

Comment: @PedroLamas no, nothing, still the same errors.

Comment: I assume you Cleaned + Built the solution, not just the project? Might sound strange, but try rebuilding it a few times in a row. Don't clean before each rebuild. See if it eventually builds successfully. Alternatively, try creating a new solution, importing your projects and building.

Comment: I tried it some ten times W/O success. It almost looks like VS imports the files twice, for every member in the .g.i.cs files have ambiguity with another member variable or method.

Comment: @PedroLamas After I commented out the files that had the errors, it build fine, and without any problems. Do you have any idea of what might have caused it, as I'm a little worried to publish it now ;)

Comment: Just to clarify, the first comment above is not entirely correct. Release mode **is** mandatory. 4.2.3 in the Application Submission Requirements (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh184844(v=VS.92).aspx) says "The application must be compiled using retail configuration instead of debug. The application must not contain debugging symbols or output." Although that doesn't always seem to be enforced as some people have submitted debug builds (usually by accident) and had the apps published.

Comment: Think I skiped that part... thank you for the correction, @Nomad101! :)

Answer (score 0):

I have developed and submitted 2 WP7 apps, both in debug mode. Both got certified for marketplace and working fine. So, Eventhough release mode is preferred, you can proceed and submit the debug version to marketplace.